# Copied failing disk with GNU ddrescue, did I miss something?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk, ddrescue

Let me explain what's in my mind so you guys can tell me if I make something wrong.

I have two external hard drives, one of which is failing(Windows tells me to format it to use it again), the second one is empty and a lot bigger so I used it to copy the failing one.
At first, I thought about using `Testdisk` because I have some experience with it. However before trying any repair tools I wanted to have a complete copy of the failing disk. That's where I found `GNU ddrescue`. 
So my plan is to make a copy with `GNU ddrescue` and then use `Testdisk` on the copy.

So I made a complete copy with the `GNU ddrescue - GUI version`. After the recovery was complete 3 options popped up for me to choose: 1.Reset 2.Mount drive 3.Exit; I am a noob when it comes to `GNU ddrescue` and I figured it would be best to just exit the program without resetting or mounting anything (I have no clue what mounting actually does to a drive, sorry).

Next, I plan to use `Testdisk` on the duplicate to recover the lost partition.

But before I move on I would like to know if I am actually right with using those two programs together or if I made any failure in the process. Am I right with thinking that the new drive is now a complete duplicate of the old one?

**Edit:**

/dev/sdd/ ... old failing hard-drive

/dev/sde/ ... new hard-drive

**`root@PartedMagic:~# sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdd`**

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Disk /dev/sdd: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Model: Portable        
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): A6D24F7F-47D5-4FAA-8595-5E56582C1DB1
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 5099 sectors (2.5 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              63       976768064   465.8 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
```

**`root@PartedMagic:~# sudo gdisk -l /dev/sde`**

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************


Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
244209734 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Disk /dev/sde: 732558336 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Model: Elements 10B8   
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): E797BEEA-722B-4903-8086-B2A84B5E741C
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 5
First usable sector is 6, last usable sector is 732558330
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 57 sectors (228.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              63       976768064   3.6 TiB     0700  Microsoft basic data
```

Output of **`sudo blkid`**

```
root@PartedMagic:~# sudo blkid
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="Expansion Drive" UUID="3C148148148105DC" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="3df9d654-01"
```

`sudo blkid` does not mention /dev/sdeX/

For clarification: /dev/sdd/ had only one partition before failing

Comment: Please [edit] and post the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdX` where `sdX` refers to the old disk and (separate invocation) the new one (possible logical sector size mismatch). Do not mount any filesystem from any of the two disks when they are both connected (duplicate UUIDs may backfire). What is the output of `sudo blkid`? (you may omit entries referring to other disks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work so easily.

The logical sector size on the new disk is `4096`, while the old disk uses `512`. Numbers in the partition table stayed the same but since new sectors are 8 times bigger, the whole partition table in the clone makes no sense.

In some cases it's possible to translate these numbers (compare [this answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511256/108618)) but here the (old) partition starts at the offset of 63*512 bytes which is not divisible by 4096. This means your filesystem now starts somewhere *inside* a bigger sector (while it should start at the beginning of a sector), so no partition table will make this work immediately.

What to do now? Some ideas below. Please disconnect the old disk (just in case) before you proceed.

---

You can still try to mount the filesystem regardless of (now invalid) partition table:

```
mount -o ro,offset=$((63*512)) /dev/sde /some/mountpoint
```

If the filesystem was healthy, this should work. In your case the command may fail because of corrupted filesystem. But maybe it will work and you'll manage to get all your important data out.

---

You can map the entire disk to a loop device that reports sector size of `512`:

```
losetup -f --show /dev/sde       # 512 is the default value
```

This should print a node like `/dev/loop7`. In the context of this device the partition table is valid. Tools that expect partition table should now work with the device (although some may require `/dev/loop7p1`, to work with the partition; `kpartx` may help but consider the next idea first).

Note: you destroy the node with `losetup -d /dev/loop7`.

---

You can map the real partition to a loop device:

```
losetup -f --show --offset $((63*512)) --sizelimit $(( (976768064+1-63)*512 )) /dev/sde
```

Again, this should print a node like `/dev/loop8`. The (possibly corrupted) filesystem starts at the very beginning of this device, so recovery tools that analyze filesystems will hopefully find it (or at least files within) without any partition table.

---

You can copy the partition to another offset, so the partition table *can* be fixed. This is somewhat tricky; all the numbers must be calculated right. If any of the previous methods was enough for you, don't bother.

Note the old disk was 465.8 GiB, the new one is 2.7 TiB; so you have plenty of space. Let's copy the filesystem to the end of the disk.

The old partition occupied 512-byte sectors from the sector number 63 to (including) 976768064, 976768002 sectors in total. This means you need at least 122096001 bigger (4096-byte) sectors for it.

In 4096-byte sectors the start and end translate to 7 (partially taken) and 122096008 (also partially taken).

Your disk holds 732558336 sectors, you need to step back by 122096001 sectors (more, if you plan to use GPT on it). A starting sector of 610459648 seems fine. It will leave some room at the end for secondary GPT (and it's aligned to a 32-MiB boundary, but it doesn't matter much). Now the last sector of the new partition should then be at least 732555648 (732555655 if you want the size in sectors to be divisible by 8, this may make some tools happy; partition bigger than enough shouldn't affect the filesystem, it knows its own size).

Edit the partition table, destroy the old (invalid) entry and create a new one as planned:

- first sector 610459648
- last sector 732555655
- code or type suitable for NTFS

Such a large disk with 512-byte sectors would need GPT, not MBR partition table. With 4096-byte sectors GPT or MBR should work.

Then (after `partprobe`, if the partitioning program doesn't call it implicitly) you should have access to the new partition.

Copy data from `/dev/loop8` (created above) to the new partition:

```
dd if=/dev/loop8 of=/dev/sdeN bs=32M
# or better use ddrescue again
```

After the command copies about 465.8 GiB, the filesystem is properly aligned within the partition (it starts at the beginning, not in the middle of a sector). Previous ideas were somewhat "hacky"; this one gives you quite a standard setup.

---

Note you can create yet another partition for recovered data if you need. The filesystem your `ddrescue` originally wrote ends at the sector 122096008. The new copy (if you decided to create it) starts at 610459648. In any case everything in between is for you to use.

Comment: That's an awesome answer mate! Luckily your first suggestion to try and mount the filesystem worked out and I got everything back. Even though your first suggestion worked out I do appreciate that you took your time and explained some more ways to get to the data. I gained a lot of knowledge from this